# CsvHelper and querying a large csv file in parallel

Tags: c#, linq, csvhelper

I have a 3.6 gig csv file. I'm using CsvHelper to work with it. When I use linq to query it, it takes a couple mins and I see the CPU only max out at about 25% on my PC. Linq seems to handle memory well when doing this as that doesn't go up much at all.

So I figured by adding .AsParallel() I should see some performance gains. When I run it with that I see my CPU go up to about 95% but it takes just as long.

Why would I not see performance gains with .AsParallel(), and is there any way to get better performance with this (leaving it as a csv).

```
string path = @"C:\my_3_gig_file.csv";

using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default)))
{
                csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
                csv.Configuration.TrimFields = true;
                var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>();

                var q1 = (from a in records.AsParallel()
                          where a.MY_HOUR == "1"
                          && a.MY_DATE == "14-JUN-13"
                          select a).ToList();
}
```

Comment: var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>(); this is whats taking the time not your linq query

Comment: That statement doesn't run at all. It comes back right away. It is the linq query.

Comment: That's wierd do maybe it's returning an IEnumerable which would happen during the linq do csv.GetRecords<MyClass>().ToList() and see if that changes the linq query

Comment: Yeah Get records is returning an IEnumerable meaning that when your running your linq its parsing it then, you need to chunk out your csv file and then parse the records in parallel once that is done, then run your linq query

Comment: Just for the record, I suggest you take a look at memory-mapped files. In your case, even if you use 1000 threads, the process would take a lot of time to complete because each iteration is accessing the file stream. With MMF, you can load the file and access it concurrently. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A memory mapped file seems interesting, but can I use linq with parallelism to query it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not gain anything by trying to process the rows in parallel so there's no point in trying.  You can only read and process the file using CsvHelper linearly.  And even then, there's not enough work there to justify the parallel processing of the rows.  What's probably hurting you is building up every single record that is read.  If there's a lot of columns, that's a lot of processing per row.

You're trying to filter out rows to use from the file.  You should read the rows in directly, check the columns, then build the records as you go.  That way, you're not wasting a lot of time building out records for each row, only to potentially throw it away.

Here's one such way you could do this.

```
List<T> GetCsvRecordsFiltered<T>(string path, Func<CsvReader, bool> filter, Action<CsvConfiguration> configure = null) where T : class
{
    using (var file = File.OpenText(path))
    using (var reader = new CsvReader(file))
    {
        configure?.Invoke(reader.Configuration);
        var result = new List<T>();
        while (reader.Read())
            if (filter(reader))
                result.Add(reader.GetRecord<T>());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then when you read the file, you'd do this:

```
var q1 = GetCsvRecordsFiltered<MyClass>(path,
    reader => reader["MY_HOUR"] == "1" && reader["MY_DATE"] == "14-JUN-13",
    config => config.TrimFields = true
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't see any performance gains using `AsParallel()` because there is nothing that can be done in parallel.

The reason that `csv.GetRecords<MyClass>()` returns right away is because it [yields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) records. It won't actually read any of the file until it needs to. Each record that is read will only read a single record from the file (actually a buffer of data).

When you're using linq, it's going to have to read the whole 3.6 GB file and parse it to get its result. There is no way that you can do a `where` clause and not have it read the entire file. The reason that doesn't happen when there are other linq provider, like with sql, is because there are indexes built, and sql is able to only pull the records it needs.